# how to access mvc model object in Extjs

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, model

I'm using Ext.net mvc and i need to access the model object from an extjs function as we do in  normal JS like <% Model %>.

Answer (score 0):

If your Ext.js code is just a script tage housed in an MVC View which is strongly typed, you can simple called `@Model.theProperty` at whatover locations in the script tag to output properties from the model

Comment: no i am using seperate script file for Extjs functions, is there an option to access the Model object from that